# How to store CGRect values in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, core-graphics

How would I store CGRect objects in a NSMutableArray, and then later retrieve them?

Answer (score 294, accepted):

You need to wrap the CG structures in `NSValue` classes. So:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray mutableArray];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)]];
CGRect someRect = [[array objectAtIndex:0] CGRectValue];
```

Comment: more examples here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/storing-cgpoint-cgsize-and-cgrect-in-collections-using-nsvalue.html

Comment: great answer! would be even more useful if you demonstrated "unboxing" of the stored NSValue back to CGRect.

Comment: Not available on MacOS

Answer (score 12):

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake( 5, 5, 40, 30 );
NSString* rectAsString = NSStringFromCGRect( rect );
CGRect original = CGRectFromString( rectAsString );
```

Comment: While this certainly works, can we please avoid promoting bad practices like this. At least add a warning about the pitfalls about this approach.

Answer (score 2):

We store the `CGRect`,`CGPoint`,`CMTime` objects in a `NSMutableArray`,

`[arrayName addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MyCGPoint]]`

`[arrayName addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:MyCGRect]]`

`[arrayName addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:MyCMTime]]`

`[arrayName addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTimeRange:MyCMTimeRange]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Store string in array.and then get back string and convert that in CGRect back as per the need.
CGRect rect = CGRectMake( 5, 5, 40, 30 );
NSString* rectAsString = NSStringFromCGRect( rect );
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray mutableArray];
[array addObject:rectAsString];

For converting string in CGRect back use:-
CGRect rect9 = CGRectFromString(rectAsString);
```